# ajax and jQuery dynamic dropdown based on other dropdown (data from Database)

Tags: php, jquery, sql, ajax

I am working on a website with a form connected to a database, the user should be able to select the date of the movie based on the movie(data gathered from the database).

I also want to display a message to the user once the form is submitted, the code for it is commented out at the end of this page, it worked but  for some reason after the message is displayed the form is not submitted to the database anymore whereas without it works normally, how could I display a message right after the form is submitted?

I have tried so many different ways and I am new to ajax, below is the code:

Index page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $('#movies').on('change',function(){
                var movieID = $(this).val();
                if(movieID){
                    $.ajax({
                        type:'POST',
                        url:'ajaxData.php',
                        data:'movieID'+movieID,
                        success:function(html){
                            $('#date').html(html);
                        }
                    });
                } else {
                    $('#date').html('<option value="">Select date/time</option>');
                }
            });
        });
    </script>
        <?php
            require_once("php/connection.php");
           
                $query = "SELECT title FROM movie";
                $result1 = mysqli_query($conn,$query);
        ?>
        <script>
            function validateForm() {
            var x = document.forms["form"]["fname"].value;
            if (x == "") {
                alert("Name must be filled out");
                return false;
            }
            }
        </script>
            <meta charset="utf-8">
            <title>Bollywood movies | Tickets</title>
            <meta name="description" content="">
            <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
            <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/Style.css">
            <script defer src="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.8/js/all.js"></script>
            <script src="js/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>

    <h1>Bollywood movies</h1>

    <section class="banner">
        <img src="images/third-serving-nLl5sJnElxY-unsplash.jpg" alt="Movies">

    </section>
   

    <nav id="navbar">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="">Home</a> </li>
            <li>  <a href="">Bookings</a> </li>
            <li> <a href="">Coming soon..</a> </li>
        </ul>
    </nav>

    <h2>You can book your tickets here!</h2>

    <form action="php/action.php" method="post" onsubmit="return validateForm()" id="form">
        <div id="first">
            <label for="fname">First Name</label><br>
            <input type="text" id="fname" name="fname" ><br>
        </div>
        <div id="last">
            <label for="lname">Last Name</label><br>
            <input type="text" id="lname" name="lname" required><br>
        </div>
        <div id="Email">
            <label for="email">Email</label><br>
            <input type="email" id="email" name="email" required><br>
        </div>
        <div id="mobile">
            <label for="Mobile_Number">Mobile Number</label><br>
            <input type="text" id="Mobile_Number" name="Mobile_Number" required><br>
        </div>
        <div id="card">
            <label for="Credit_card">Credit card number</label><br>
            <input type="tel" id="Credit_card" name="credit" ><br>
        </div>
        <div id="Movies">
            <label for="movies">Movie selection</label><br>
            <select name="movies" id="movies">
            <option selected="" disabled="">Select movie</option>
            <?php 
            while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result1)):; ?>
                <option value=" <?php echo $row[0]; ?>"><?php echo $row[0];?></option>
             <?php endwhile;
            ?>
            </select> <br>
        </div>
        <div id="Date">
            <label for="date">Session date/time</label><br>
            <select name="date" id="date" >
            <option value="">Select date/time</option>
        </div>
        <br>
        <br>
        <hr>
        <div id="submit">
            <input type="submit" value="Submit">
            <input type="reset">
        </div>
        <br>
        <div id="yes"> </div>
    </form>
      
    <script>
            $("#fname").change(function() {
            if ($(this).val() .length == 0) {
            $('#last').hide();
            } else {
            $('#last').show();
            }
            });
            $("#fname").trigger("change");
            
            $("#lname").change(function() {
            if ($(this).val() .length == 0) {
            $('#Email').hide();
            } else {
            $('#Email').show();
            }
            });
            $("#lname").trigger("change");
            
            $("#email").change(function() {
            if ($(this).val() .length == 0) {
            $('#mobile').hide();
            } else {
            $('#mobile').show();
            }
            });
            $("#email").trigger("change");
            
            $("#Mobile_Number").change(function() {
            if ($(this).val() .length == 0) {
            $('#card').hide();
            } else {
            $('#card').show();
            }
            });
            $("#Mobile_Number").trigger("change");
            
            $("#Credit_card").change(function() {
            if ($(this).val() .length == 0) {
            $('#Movies').hide();
            } else {
            $('#Movies').show();
            }
            });
            $("#Credit_card").trigger("change");
            
            $("#movies").change(function() {
            if ($(this).val() .length == 0) {
            $('#Date').hide();
            } else {
            $('#Date').show();
            }
            });
            $("#movies").trigger("change"); 
    </script>

<!-- <script>
            var name= $('#fname').val() ;
            var lname= $('#lname').val() ;            

            $('#form').submit(function() {
            $('#yes').text("Thank you for your booking, " + $( '#fname' ).val() + " " + $('#lname').val() );
            return false;
            });
    </script> -->


</html>
```

ajax page:

```
<?php
include_once 'php/connection.php';

if(!empty($_POST["movieID"])){

    $query = "SELECT sessionDate FROM sessions WHERE movieID = ".$_POST['movieID']." " ;
    $result = $db->query($query);
        
    if($result->num_rows > 0){
        echo '<option value="">Select date/time</option>';
        while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
            echo'<option value="'.$row['movieID'].'">'.row['sessionDate'].'</option>';
        }
    } else {
        echo '<option value="">Date not available</option>';
    }

}
?>
```

connection page:

```
<?php
// Set the values for the variables
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$database = "bollywood_movies";

// Connect to the mySQL database
$conn = @mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $database);

// Check for valid connection. If there are errors display a error message and error details

if (!$conn) {
    echo "Error: Unable to connect to MySQL." . PHP_EOL;
    echo "Debugging errno: " . mysqli_connect_errno() . PHP_EOL; // Display the MySQL error number
    echo "Debugging error: " . mysqli_connect_error() . PHP_EOL; // Display the MySQL error details
    exit;
}
?>
```

action page:

```
<?php
// MySQL Database Connect
require_once("connection.php");
// Read the values from the form
$first_name = $_POST['fname'];
$last_name = $_POST['lname'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$mobile = $_POST['Mobile_Number'];
$movieID = $POST['movies'];
$sessionDate = $_POST['date'];
// escape variables for security
$first_name = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $first_name);
$last_name = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $last_name);
$email = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $email);
$mobile = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $mobile);
$movieID = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $movieID);
$sessionDate = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $sessionDate);

// create the INSERT query
$query="INSERT INTO patron (first_name, last_name, email, mobile) VALUES ('$first_name', '$last_name','$email', '$mobile' )";
$results = mysqli_query($conn, $query );

if(!$results) {
    echo ("Query error: " . mysqli_error($conn));
    exit;
}
else {
    // Redirect the browser window back to the add customer page
    header("location: ../index.php");
}
?>
```

Database data:

```
--
-- Table structure for table `booking`
--
CREATE TABLE `booking` (
  `bookingID` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `patronID` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `sessionID` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `paid` tinyint(1) DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4;
```

---

```
--
-- Table structure for table `movie`
--
CREATE TABLE `movie` (
   `movieID` int(11) NOT NULL,
   `title` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
   `description` text NOT NULL,
   `year` int(4) NOT NULL,
   `active` tinyint(1) DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4;

--
-- Dumping data for table `movie`
--
INSERT INTO `movie` (`movieID`, `title`, `description`, `year`, `active`) VALUES
(1, 'The Godfather', 'Gangsters movie with plenty of suspance', 1972, 1),
(2, 'Raging Bull', 'The story of a bull that was raging', 1980, 1),
(3, 'Schindlers list', 'history movie about the war', 1993, 1),
(4, 'The Shawshank Redemption', 'The redemption of the shanks', 1994, 1),
(5, 'Casablanca', 'Crime and action', 1942, 1);
```

---

```
--
-- Table structure for table `patron`
--
CREATE TABLE `patron` (
  `patronID` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `first_name` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
  `last_name` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
  `email` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `mobile` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4;
```

---

```
--
-- Table structure for table `sessions`
--
CREATE TABLE `sessions` (
  `sessionID` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `movieID` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `sessionDate` datetime DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4;

--
-- Dumping data for table `sessions`
--
INSERT INTO `sessions` (`sessionID`, `movieID`, `sessionDate`) VALUES
(1, 1, '2020-12-23 18:51:33'),
(2, 2, '2020-12-16 10:25:33'),
(3, 3, '2020-12-31 09:51:33'),
(4, 4, '2020-12-29 11:51:33'),
(5, 5, '2020-12-17 22:51:33');
```

Indexes for dumped tables

```
--
-- Indexes for table `booking`
--
ALTER TABLE `booking`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`bookingID`),
  ADD KEY `patronID` (`patronID`),
  ADD KEY `sessionID` (`sessionID`);

--
-- Indexes for table `movie`
--
ALTER TABLE `movie`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`movieID`);

--
-- Indexes for table `patron`
--
ALTER TABLE `patron`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`patronID`);

--
-- Indexes for table `sessions`
--
ALTER TABLE `sessions`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`sessionID`),
  ADD KEY `movieID` (`movieID`);
```

AUTO_INCREMENT for dumped tables

```
--
-- AUTO_INCREMENT for table `booking`
--
ALTER TABLE `booking`
  MODIFY `bookingID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT;

--
-- AUTO_INCREMENT for table `movie`
--
ALTER TABLE `movie`
  MODIFY `movieID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, AUTO_INCREMENT=6;

--
-- AUTO_INCREMENT for table `patron`
--
ALTER TABLE `patron`
  MODIFY `patronID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, AUTO_INCREMENT=34;

--
-- AUTO_INCREMENT for table `sessions`
--
ALTER TABLE `sessions`
  MODIFY `sessionID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, AUTO_INCREMENT=6;
```

Constraints for dumped tables

```
--
-- Constraints for table `booking`
--
ALTER TABLE `booking`
  ADD CONSTRAINT `booking_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`patronID`) REFERENCES `patron` (`patronID`),
  ADD CONSTRAINT `booking_ibfk_2` FOREIGN KEY (`sessionID`) REFERENCES `sessions` (`sessionID`);

--
-- Constraints for table `sessions`
--
ALTER TABLE `sessions`
  ADD CONSTRAINT `sessions_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`movieID`) REFERENCES `movie` (`movieID`);
COMMIT;
```

Thanks you so much for your help in advance, I hope that I will be able to solve this problem as I have been working on it for a while.

Comment: Just to add some more information, the movies dropdown works correctly,  I have been trying to populate the date session dropdown based on the movie selection by using Ajax through jQuery , it is not working at this stage but I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong (no error messages either).

Answer (score 0):

If I understand it correctly you want a message to appear after the form is submitted not before, because having it appear before stops the form from being submitted? If you're returning to the page after the form is submitted would you be able to set a variable in the header so that a peace of php code could `$_GET` the variable and use that to display the message sort of like this

```
<?php if(isset($_GET['formsubmit']) && $_GET['formsubmit'] == 'pass'){echo'$('#yes').text("Thank you for your booking, '.$_SEASSON['firstname'].' '.$_SEASSON['lastname']).'.';'}?>
```

or if you don't want to set the names as session variables maybe just set a parton_id or something and have a query to fetch the relevant information for the form. Not sure this really count as an answer but I don't have a good enough reputation to comment.

Comment: Hi Harrison and thanks for your comment, my main goal is to populate the date dropdown based on the movies dropdown of the form, and then display a successful message once the form is submitted.